# Wordpress Page.ly MultiEdit Plugin Not Working

Tags: html, wordpress, plugins, themes

I'm trying to use the Wordpress page.ly MultiEdit plugin here:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pagely-multiedit/

I can't get it to work correctly. I get an error:

Bottom, Left, Bottom, Left region(s) are not declared in the template.

Here's a screenshot.

[image]

Here is the code for the template file I created:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Home
MultiEdit: Right
*/

?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


    <div class="content">

            <?php the_content(); ?>


    </div>

    <div class="sidecontent">
            <?php multieditDisplay(‘Right’); ?>

            </div>



    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>


            <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I didn't look at your code close enough.  You're not calling them twice in the code, you're just not calling them at all.  You can still follow the instructions in my answer and it will work.

---

Couple things here.  It looks like you're calling the same two content blocks twice in the same page template.  You can't do that.  Each one has to have its own unique name.  If you're simply trying to get "bottom', "left", and "right" you need to change you're comment code at the top of the page template.

Use this:

```
/*
Template Name: Home
MultiEdit: Bottom,Left,Right
*/
```

Then place these where you want the content to be displayed in your page template:

```
<?php multieditDisplay('Bottom'); ?>

<?php multieditDisplay('Left'); ?>

<?php multieditDisplay('Right'); ?>
```

Before you do any of that though, click on the "Screen Options" tab in the top corner of the admin page for your home page editor.  Then click on the "Custom Fields" option.  Then scroll down until you see the "Custom Fields" area and expand it.  Then click on the "Show/Hide Multiedit Fields" so that you can see the ones you currently have in there.  You need to delete each one of them to clear them from your editor.  Follow these instructions and it will work, its an amazing plugin that I've used many times with great success.  Once you fix it, please accept my answer.  Let me know if you have any other issues with it.

Also, you don't need to use the call inside of a loop, just drop in the one of the three calls where you need it to be in the template.  In fact, I'd recommend not using it inside of a loop.

Comment: Deleting the MultiEdit Fields worked great thanks! I was also wondering if there was a way to use this plugin alongside this one: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multiple-content-blocks/ Is it possible to have the multiedit regions for each content block? Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, glad i could help.  I don't know that other plugin though, I've never used it.  I don't really see why you'd need to do that though.  You can add as many editable regions as you want with Page.ly Multiedit. Just define them in your comment and then call them where ever you'd like them to display.

Comment: Yes, but I'm planning on having four different content areas with 2-4 editable regions each so I'm trying to find a way to add multiple text editors with multiple tabs on them for the different regions. That way I wouldn't have one text editor with 12 tabs.